# Software to partially remove text from file names

Tags: file-management, rename

I'm looking for a software which can remove some parts of file names:

i.e.: `very_long_name.jpg` to `name.jpg`

Comment: What is your platform (please indicate it in the tags when you ask such a generic question)?

Comment: I removed "images" from your question tags as it's not really related to images specifically; it's more a general file renaming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a Windows OS, I like [Ken Rename](http://ken-rename.en.softonic.com/) for this purpose.

[image]

Comment: This one looks great! thank you all for all your input!

Answer (score 4):

This bat file will do the trick;

```
for %%i in (very_long_*.jpg) do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
rename %fname% %fname:~10%
```

where "10" is the length of the prefix you wish to remove. (In this case, "very_long_"). Tested on windows 7.

Comment: /flex. Who needs 3rd party software. ;)

Answer (score 2):

My favorite is [Lupas Rename](http://rename.lupasfreeware.org/lupasrename.php), which in my view is the swiss-knife of renamers:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [**ReNamer**](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/denrenamer.html), which is my favorite renaming freeware.

> ReNamer is a small, yet very flexible
>   file and folder renamer, that offers
>   all the standard renaming procedures,
>   including prefixes, suffixes,
>   replacements, case changes as well as
>   advanced options and support for
>   Unicode file names. In addition, it
>   can also remove brackets, add number
>   sequences, remove digits or symbols
>   and change file extensions. The
>   program allows you to combine multiple
>   renaming actions as a rule set,
>   applying each action in logical
>   sequence. Renamer supports 60
>   different meta fields, including EXIF,
>   ID3 and others, that can be used as
>   part of the new file name. Advanced
>   users can use PascalScript to program
>   their own renaming rules.

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows:

**[Multi File Renamer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/multifilerename/)** is open source and works on Windows 7.

[image: Multi File Renamer]

#### Mac:

**[Name Mangler](http://manytricks.com/namemangler/)** is freeware.

[image]

*Note: the platform not specified, so I provided two options.*

Answer (score 1):

Another option that I've been using on Windows for quite a while is [Rename Master](http://www.joejoesoft.com/cms/showpage.php?cid=108).

*From the site:*

> This utility will add, remove, or
>   replace parts of the filename with
>   ease and also supports renaming via
>   file properties, MP3 tags, JPEG JFIF
>   and EXIF tags, and text files. Batch
>   renaming that's simple to use, yet
>   still very powerful.
>
> [image: Rename Master Screenshot]
>
> **Features**
>   - Intelligent number sorting
>   - JPEG/MP3 tag support and many more Meta-Variables
>   - Auto-Preview support
>   - "Scipts" to save commonly used renaming options
>   - [*] and [?] command prompt style wildcards for replacing and remove
>   options
>   - "Undo" button so a renaming operation can be rolled back
>   - Floating thumbnail window for viewing pictures and optional
>   thumbnail file list view
>   - Optional Explorer integration for right-clicking on folders or using
>   "Send To"

Best of all, there's no install file, so it's portable for Windows systems.