# Find file names that is partially the same

Tags: windows-7

Looking for a software that can find and remove based on parts of file names.

For example (file names):

```
"This is not, for this is right"
"This is not  cause it is wrong"
```

It would find these because they start with the same characters.
Then I want to remove all with **`wrong`** in them.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you asking to find all files that have a particular word in their name, and remove those?

Comment: What I need is a software that find files where the first X characters is the same and THEN remove files based on input from the user.
For example:
Software - europe
Software - america
Klipsch - europe
Klipsch - america

So the software would find these four because they share the same start characters and then I could remove all of them inclyding europe.

Comment: `dir Software*` does not give you that list?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Software to partially remove text from file names](http://superuser.com/questions/88625/software-to-partially-remove-text-from-file-names)

Comment: I can actually wanna REMOVE one of the files with partial same file name. But I wanna be able to CHOOSE

Answer (score 1):

Try this freeware - Everything: http://voidtools.com/ should do what you want and very quick and easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that searching for "beginning of text*" without the quotes is not an option for you. I recommend a free tool to [find similar file names](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-About.htm).

This is a tool that has commercial version, but the options to find duplicate files and files with similar names are unrestricted. It can detect for example: My CV.doc, My new CV.doc, My Cv 2013.doc and so on. You can adjust the similarity percentage for the search.

Actually it can even select all the files that contain certain word for you like "Wrong" in the results in order to delete them automatically, but that is available in the paid version. See the quick-check preview here: http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-Screenshots.htm
You can even specify multiple words or phrases to be matched.

I think it will do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Another Freeware alternative is [Anti-Twin](http://www.joerg-rosenthal.com/en/antitwin/) (which I have nothing to do with other than using it from time to time for purposes similar to those of the OP)
 It's not a very stable or fast or program but it does have the (afaik) unique feature of allowing you to compare and match files based on a user-set percentage of the filename(s).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to delete files that start with "This is not" and end with "wrong".  If that is the case, you can use the following command line command:

```
DEL "This is not*wrong.*"
```

Comment: I wanna find files within a set of files that share X character in the of the file.
Within this selection I wanna delete all the files with "wrong" in the name

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, another option is to use a Unix solution. 
Install Cygwin or some other Unix lookalike, and pipe a sorted (by name) file listing
into an `awk` script that compares consecutive lines.